# How to fade out an Alert::widget after some seconds?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

For showing the alert I am using this code in my view.

```
<?= Alert::widget() ?>
```

And From controller I am setting the flash by using this code:

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us.');
```

Now I want to hide this flash automatically after some seconds, How can I do this?

Comment: which Alert widget is this `yii\bootstrapAlert` or `yii\widgets\Alert` ?

Comment: `setTimeout(3000, function(){ $(".info").fadeOut("slow"); });` ? as here: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I am using `yii\widgets\Alert`

Comment: @DavidWinder I tried it but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `javascript` method to hide or `fadeOut()` the alert on top of your layout file if you are including the `yii\widgets\Alert` widget in the layout for overall usage on your site.

```
$js=<<< JS
     $(".alert").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut("slow");
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

You can adjust the timeout accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! It is working but I am not getting your code, Will you please explain it?

Comment: I have updated the code so tha it is more readable, all i am doing is setting the delay for the  `fadeOut()` by applying the `fadeOut()` to the `.alert` element which is our alert obviously , it fades out the alert message after 3 seconds @BilalSaqib