# How to remove error flash message without page reloading or manual closing in Yii2 php?

Tags: php, html, user-interface, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

my view page is located in [site/files] as shown on screenshot:[image]

when I enter wrong hash to download a file I get error flash message. But after, when the hash is true and downloading process begins, flash message still remains.

my controller is as follows:

```
    public function actionDownload()
   {
       $uploadDir = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/upload/temporary/');
       $hash = Yii::$app->request->post('TempFiles')['download_hash'];
       $file = TempFiles::find()->where(['download_hash' => $hash])->one();
       if($file !== null) {
           Yii::$app->getResponse()->sendFile($uploadDir . $file->name, $file->name);
           Yii::$app->getResponse()->send();
       } else{
           Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'download error');
           return $this -> redirect(['/site/files']);
       }
   }

   public function actionFiles(){
        $model = new TempFiles();
       return $this -> render('files', ['model' => $model]);

   }
```

my view is as follows:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model \backend\models\TempFiles */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="file-download">
    <div class="hero"><h2>file downloading</h2></div>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-download', 'action' => ['/site/download'], 'options' => ['class' => 'form form-centered'], 'fieldConfig' => ['options' => ['class' => 'form-item']]]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'download_hash')->textInput(['autofocus' => true, 'maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <div class="form-item">
        <?= Html::submitButton('download file', ['class' => 'button primary width-100']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

I wanna remove flash message programmatically without page reloading or manual closing if text entered was correct after first attempt. I tried removeflash, redirect, refresh and so on, but everything without success. How to overcome my problem? Where the hidden rat?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check alert widget

Comment: The message stays there because the browser doesn't redraw the page when it receives the reply with file download. You have to use javascript to remove the message when the hash input changes or when the form is submitted again. If you want more specific answer you will have to provide the code from your layout that outputs the flash messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fade out an Alert::widget after some seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151809/how-to-fade-out-an-alertwidget-after-some-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to hide flash messages automatically after some time (3 seconds in the example below) after display.

```
<?php $this->registerJs('$(".alert").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut("slow");', View::POS_READY); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it disappear with pure JS or use yii

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
    'myHideEffect',
    '$(".info").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut("slow");',
    CCClientScript::POS_READY
);
?>
```

see more [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages)